# Rails mysql update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails, I came from PHP and i've realised it's not just as simple as getting syntax down, there's a lot of good structure practices to take on board too.

While what I have currently works, I'm almost certain I'm not doing it the best way.

Here's what I'm doing. I'm tracking clicks via AJAX and updating a record in the database to monitor popular access points.

Here's my controller:

```
class AjaxController < ApplicationController

  def track    
    elem = Tracking.where('element = ?', params[:element]).first
    if elem.nil?
      Tracking.create(:element => params[:element], :count => 0)
    else
      elem.count = elem.count + 1
      elem.save
    end
    render :text => 'ok'
  end

  def validate
    if request.xhr? && respond_to?(params[:callback])
      return self.send(params[:callback])
    end
    no_access
  end

  private

  def no_access
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

Here's my model:

```
class Tracking < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :element, :count
end
```

tracking table:

```
+-------------------------+
| id | element    | count |
+-------------------------+
| 1  | bazinga    |   3   |
---------------------------
```

Could anyone steer me in the right direction, if something could be refactored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would see some re-factoring with regarding to Rails conversions. But these can be over rolled, if you have any specific reason.

*1 - Your model name (I think this you got right, just double check the table name)*

Ideally Rails will have the tables in plural and models in the singular. so your table should be `trackings` and your model should be `Tracking`

*2 - controller*

Since you are referring to your Tracking model, by convention, the controller name should be `TrackingsController`,

And Rails uses a REST approach, so try your best to keep your default 7 controller actions (as long as they are meaningful in the context). default REST controller actions are

```
index

show

new

create

edit

update

destroy
```

So I think your click can be matched as `Trackings -> create`

and probably no_access method can be moved to ApplicationController, as it can be used by any controller

*Program logic*

Normally we don't write the domain login in controller, so your below part in controller

```
elem = Tracking.where('element = ?', params[:element]).first
if elem.nil?
  Tracking.create(:element => params[:element], :count => 0)
else
  elem.count = elem.count + 1
  elem.save
end
```

can be moved to model like

```
class Tracking < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :element, :count

  def self.track(params)
    #your creation and counter update login
  end

end
```

and in your controller

```
def create
    Tracking.track(params)
    render :text => 'ok'
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller could benefit from some RESTful design. Make your controller work with resources -- AjaxController is not an example of this.

DRY your code by moving `no_access` to the `ApplicationController` and adding [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authorization.

Your model is fine, though you may want validation. And to specify not null in the schema.

Finally, keep reading other peoples code. And keep writing your own code. And you'll get better in time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what sameera207 said, You can probably shorten the process of finding or creating the record with `find_or_create_` methods:

```
Tracking.find_or_create_by_element(params[:element])
```

**Edit**

You can handle the incremented value with:

```
tracking = Tracking.find_or_create_by_element(params[:element]) do |t|
  t.count = 1
end
tracking.count += 1
tracking.save
```

Comment: I read about that, the problem is i'll be incrementing the count if it exists.